# Unable to uninstall program from SBS 2008

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, uninstall, teamviewer

Running SBS 2008, installed trial of Teamviewer. Decided to take it as didnt want to buy full version.

Went Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Uninstalled Teamviewer.

The uninstallation froze halfway through so i killed the process in Task Manager.

Now back in Programs and Features, Teamviewer has gone (hence cant uninstall it) but still remains in the Program Files folder and i can still run it!?

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't there an (un)installer in the Teamviewer-folder in the Program Files folder?

Comment: Nice, forgot about that!